# How ink! handles DispatchError from ChainExtension

Tags: ink, smart-contract, chain-extension

ChainExtension will return `Result<RetVal, DispatchError>`. (As you can see in the bottom pircutre)

- When ChainExtension implementation returns `Ok(RetVal::Converging(1))` and handle that status code 1 on ink! contract side like below, then Extrinsic itself will be shown as success event even if dispatch failed.

```
impl ink_env::chain_extension::FromStatusCode for ContractErrorCode {
    fn from_status_code(status_code: u32) -> Result<(), Self> {
        match status_code {
            0 => Ok(()),
            1 => Err(Self::Failed),
            _ => panic!("encountered unknown status code"),
        }
    }
}
```

(What I did for experiments was ignore `Error(DispatchError)` and return `Ok(RetVal::Converging(1))` instead so that ink! can handle status code 1.)
[image]

- When it returns `DispatchError` (Extrinsic itself fail), ink! smart contract cannot handle it and return its failure reason with `#[message]` functions' returned value. for e.g. `Result<(), ContractError>` (here ContractError reflects DispatchError's reason and perhaps we'd like to show it on UI).

**The question is
What is the appropriate way for ink! smart contract messages to handle DispatchError (from ChainExtension) and return it as its returned value?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> The question is What is the appropriate way for ink! smart contract messages to handle `DispatchError` (from `ChainExtension`) and return it as its returned value?

How I understand your question is that you want for the frontend to have the information that an error occurred while calling a contract. And specifically that it was  a `DispatchError` in a chain extension.

The problem that you face when returning `RetVal::Diverging` from a chain extension's `fn call` is that Substrate will emit an event `ExtrinsicFailed(pallet_contracts::ContractReverted)` without the information that it was a `DispatchError`.

What you can do is to throw the `DispatchError` immediately in your `fn call`. This will then result in an `ExtrinsicFailed` event being emitted on-chain, containing the info that it was a dispatch error.

So in the code from your screenshot it would be:

```rust
let result =
  RmrkExtension::execute_func::<E>(func_id_matcher, env)?;
```

Comment: Actually, I didn't use ` ::ink_env::chain_extension::ChainExtensionMethod` and its method `handle_error_code` at that time when I asked question. Then `ContractReverted` event itself wasn't emitted without using it.

After using `handle_error_code` method properly, substrate emits `ContractReverted` event when returned RetVal from chain extension mapped to Err on contract side (by `from_status_code` impl).

So, now, we can do both getting `ExtrinsicFailed ContractReverted` event + contract  receiving dispatch error reason from status code (RetVal)

Comment: Thank you so much!